# CakePHP - Can I redirect to a specific DIV of a view after success

Tags: cakephp

All,

I wanted to find out if it is possible to redirect to a specific `<DIV>` within a VIEW.

Basically, after the user clicks submit in the view and the submission is a success I would like to redirect the user to a specific `<DIV ID=>` within a view.

This is code I am currently using

```
$this->redirect(array('action'=>'view',$id));
```

This would redirect the user to http://cakephexample/articles/view/4. However I would like to have them transferred to http://cakephpexample/articles/view/4#comments.

How can that be accomplished with the redirect option?

thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried `$this->redirect(array('action'=>'view', $id, '#comments'));`?

Comment: Yes this works as well as the following `$this->redirect('action'=>'view',$id.'#comments');`. Thank you for the tip.