# redirect to the modal ( automatic open bootstrap modal) after failing condition in cakephp controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

The problem here is if user not filled address redirect the user to fill the modal address by automatically opening the Bootstrap modal

Here is my controller code

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        ['address_line_1']);
        if($this->request->data['PropManagementAddress']['address_line_1'] == null){
        $this->redirect(array('#myModal'));
        //$this->Session->setFlash(__('Add Address by pressing add button below'));
        }else {

        $this->PropManagementUser->create();
        if ($this->PropManagementUser->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            //prd($this->PropManagementUser->validationErrors);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
```

here is my `add.ctp` code

```
<label>Add Address </label>
<button type="button" class="form-group" style="margin-left:140px;"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">addrress</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('PropManagementAddress.address_line_1',array('div' => array('class'=>'form-group'),'placeholder' => 'address line 1','label' => 'Address Line 1','class' => 'form-control'));
                echo $this->Form->input('PropManagementAddress.address_line_2',array('div' => array('class'=>'form-group'),'placeholder' => 'address line 2','label' => 'Address Line 2','class' => 'form-control'));
                echo $this->Form->input('PropManagementAddress.city_id',array('div' => array('class'=>'form-group'),'type'=>'select','options'=>$cities,'placeholder' =>'city id','label' => 'City ID','class' => 'form-control'));
                echo $this->Form->input('PropManagementAddress.state_id',array('div' => array('class'=>'form-group'),'type'=>'select','options'=>$states,'label' => 'State ID','class' => 'form-control'));
                echo $this->Form->input('PropManagementAddress.country_id',array('div' => array('class'=>'form-group'),'placeholder' =>'country id','label' => 'Country ID','class' => 'form-control'));
                echo $this->Form->input('PropManagementAddress.pincode',array('div' => array('class'=>'form-group'),'type'=>'text','placeholder' => 'pincode','label' => 'Pincode','class' => 'form-control'));
                echo $this->Form->input('PropManagementAddress.longitude',array('div' => array('class'=>'form-group'),'type'=>'text','placeholder' => 'longitude','label' => 'Longitude','class' => 'form-control'));
                echo $this->Form->input('PropManagementAddress.latitude',array('div' => array('class'=>'form-group'),'type'=>'text','placeholder' => 'latitude','label' => 'Latitude','class' => 'form-control'));
                ?>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: what i tried is here [just check out with this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323649/cakephp-can-i-redirect-to-a-specific-div-of-a-view-after-success)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach.

In your controller:

```
if ($this->PropManagementUser->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved.'));
     return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
 } else {
     $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
     $this->set('showModal',true); 
 }
```

In your view:

```
<?php if (!empty($showModal)):?>
    <?php $this->Html->scriptStart(array('inline'=>false))?>

        $('#myModal').modal('show');

    <?php $this->Html->scriptEnd()?>
<?php endif ?>
```

See [`.modal('show')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modalshow) in the Bootstrap docs.

Answer (score 0):

Yup I got the answer, I written script in my ctp cakephp view

```
<script>
$('#submit').click(function(e){
   if($.trim($('#address_line_1').val()) == ''){
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        e.preventDefault();
       }
});
</script>
```

above textbox id in the model is address_line_1 which is I have to check for empty or not.